# Angular *ngIf <mat-slide-toggle >

Tags: angular

how to open the `<mat-slide-toggle>` if the **currentFight** is in **bet-open** and **on-going** and how to close the `<mat-slide-toggle>` if the **currentFight** is in `on-standby` and `last-call` ?

```
<label class="mb-10 mr-15">Close </label> 
    <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="isSlideChecked"></mat-slide-toggle>
<label class="mb-10 ml-15">Open </label>
```

this is my type script

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-odds-editor',
  templateUrl: './odds-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./odds-editor.component.scss']
})
export class OddsEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() currentFight: any;
  constructor() { }
  public isSlideChecked: boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  toggleChanges($event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    if(this.currentFight){
      if(this.currentFight == 'on-standby'){
        this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
      }
      else if(this.currentFight == 'bet-open'){
        this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
      }
      else if(this.currentFight == 'last-call'){
        this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
      }
      else if(this.currentFight == 'on-going'){
        this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
      }
    // if currentFight
    // this.isSlideChecked = $event.checked;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<mat-slide-toggle>` should have a `[checked]` input property that you can bind to.

This should show the toggle as selected.

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="true"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

This should show the toggle as not selected.

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="false"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

You can replace value of the `[checked]` property with a variable from your component if you need to be able to select/de-select the slider from your code.

The official documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/examples

**Updated:**

Try changing your html to

```
<label class="mb-10 mr-15">Close </label> 
    <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="isSlideChecked()"></mat-slide-toggle>
<label class="mb-10 ml-15">Open </label>
```

and your ts to

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-odds-editor',
  templateUrl: './odds-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./odds-editor.component.scss']
})
export class OddsEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() currentFight: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  isSlideChecked() {
    if(this.currentFight == 'on-standby' || this.currentFight == 'bet-open'){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, thanks for answering my question, please see the updated question